# DateTimePicker seems to be an hour off?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following code in my React application:

```
import { DateTimePicker, LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";
import { AdapterMoment } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterMoment";
import moment from "moment";
...
    const [job, setJob] = useState({
        name: "",
        outgoingDateTime: moment("2022-09-01T21:00:00"),
    });

    const handleOutgoingDateTimeChange = (newValue) => { setJob({...job, outgoingDateTime: newValue}); }
...

                                <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={ AdapterMoment }>
                                    <Stack spacing={2} direction="row">
                                        <DateTimePicker
                                            label="Outgoing Date and Time"
                                            value={ job.outgoingDateTime }
                                            onChange={ handleOutgoingDateTimeChange }
                                            inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
                                            ampm={ false }
                                            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />} />
                                    </Stack>
                                </LocalizationProvider>
```

When I then enter something like 2022-09-13T21:05:00.000Z into the `DateTimePicker` and then submit and output the result, I have this:

```
Job Outgoing Date Time: "2022-09-13T20:05:00.000Z"
```

Which is clearly an hour behind what I've tried to submit which is not what I want as I asked for 21:05 for example. How can I fix this to show the correct time when I submit it?

Comment: When you say "enter", are you typing in an input box?  If so, maybe `inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"` is affecting how it's interpreted and maybe using a more ISO-like input format would help.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I did think the same thing, however, I removed ```inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm"``` and the issue still remained.

Comment: Removing the inputFormat probably means it uses some default which may still not be the pattern you want.  Maybe using an ISO like format string like `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`, assuming its using conventions like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Sorry, where would I put that exactly?